# onSubmit not working when trying to get a result

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am submitting a questionnaire and trying to get the result using the onSubmit but it is not working

**JavaScript**

```
function results_addition(){
  var results = total + Details + formElement;

  if(results<30){
    document.submit_form.choice1.value="Low Risk";
  }else{
    if(results>50){
      document.submit_form.choice1.value="High Risk";
    }else{
      document.submit_form.choice1.value="Medium Risk";
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="choice1" onSubmit="results_addition()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: close the input tag `<input/>`

Comment: "var results = total + Details + formElement;"  total, Details and formElement is declared in another place?

Comment: Could you provide the some more JavaScript code ?

Comment: var total = 0;
    var Details = " ";
    var formElement;

Answer (score 0):

please try `onsubmit` instead of `onSubmit`, then add a closing `</form>` tag

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still not getting the result :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts some text.</p>

<form name="choice1" onSubmit="results_addition()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function results_addition(){
alert("hello")
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the same form and it is working I think you have not closed the form properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change

   `<form name="choice1" onSubmit="results_addition()">`

   to

   `<form name="choice1" onSubmit="return results_addition()">`
2. Add the following at the end of the function

   `return false;`

Comment: function results_addition(){
  var results = total + Details + formElement;

  if(results<30){
    document.submit_form.choice1.value="Low Risk";
  }else{
    if(results>50){
      document.submit_form.choice1.value="High Risk";
    }else{
      document.submit_form.choice1.value="Medium Risk";
    }
  }
  return false;
}

Comment: Thank you for the help im just confused where the result high.medium or low risk will appear any help in that would be appreciated

Comment: Could you post your entire html file, or share it somewhere online like https://jsfiddle.net/. So I can have better idea what are you trying to do and provide you the solution. thanks

Comment: i have put it on jsfiddle.net Nesar

Comment: Once you paste your code in jsfiddle, you have to save it and you will get a link like "https://jsfiddle.net/h1ojnuj4/".

Alternatively, you can put your code in the link I've created. Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/h1ojnuj4/

Comment: Hi, I just went to the link, and it's empty. I think I have to give you permission exclusively. Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/h1ojnuj4/3/#&togetherjs=Cdijxi2qjR 
Don't forget to update once you are done, and paste the link jsfiddle will generate after you update the code.

Comment: That's great, However you forgot to copy the link and share with me here. After you update, jsfiddle will generate new url, kindly share that with me, or if you have that coding running somewhere in the server you can share the link with me. else just paste all the codes here.